# making a selectboxlist from database and show it in a view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I used this code for making data for selectbox and used viewbag to send it to view:

```
 ViewBag.category_id = new SelectList(db.categories, "id", "title");
                return View();
```

[image]

and in my view to show the selectbox I used this code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("category_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

but when I run my project I get this error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db.Categories is a lazy-loaded IEnumerable<> of all of the categories in your database.  You should use ToList() to evaluate that IEnumerable<> just like you did with your other queries:

```
ViewBag.category_id = new SelectList(db.categories.ToList(), "id", "title");
```